# Opendkim проверка своих писем

Tags: postfix, dkim

Собственно настроен почтовый сервер Postfix для подписи используется OpenDKIM

Есть задача с которой уже не знаю что делать.. 
Задача: 
 - Есть 2 домена example.com example.net 
 - Оба обслуживаются моим постфиксом (поднят еще свой локальный dns) на example.com настроен DKIM 
 - при отправки с почты example.com - подпись создается 
 Как добиться того, что бы эти же письма проверялись...

Конфиг opendkim :

```
    AutoRestart Yes
AutoRestartRate 10/1h
PidFile /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
Mode sv
Syslog yes
SyslogSuccess yes
LogWhy yes
UserID opendkim:opendkim
Socket inet:8891@localhost
Umask 022
Canonicalization relaxed/relaxed
Selector default
MinimumKeyBits 1024
KeyFile /etc/postfix/dkim/mail.example.com.private
KeyTable /etc/postfix/dkim/keytable
SigningTable refile:/etc/postfix/dkim/signingtable
```

Письма подписывает - но не проверяет 
Из вне не могу отправить письмо по понятным причинам

Comment: добился того что если отправлять почту с адреса который не имеет dkim появляется Authentication-Results: mail.example.com; dkim=none

Это с .net -> .com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

конфигурация в теле была верная, но была проблема с постфиксом - переустанавливал, все завелось.